# Where can I find OCC TIMS methodology?

Tags: margin

I searched the web, but could not find OCC TIMS methodology detailed description anywhere. Any ideas?

[OCC TIMS](https://www.theocc.com/risk-management/customer-portfolio-margin)

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked at this but my understanding (which can be out dated) is that it's the exact same as CME's span methodology with the exception of TIMS using the binomial pricing model for options.